# How exactly is the cost-complexity parameter in rpart selected?

Tags: r, classification, cross-validation, rpart

I read the description of rpart and some other sources about classification trees. Still, I'm not sure if I completely understood how rpart selects these parameters.
I would appreciate it if someone can give me a feedback whether the following understanding is correct. Thank you!

Rpart initially and automatically splits the data into training and validation sets. It then creates a sequence of minimising subtrees and complexity-parameters on the training set. Then the error-rate on all subtrees is calculated using the validation set. This is repeated k times (for k-fold CV) and eventually the cross-validation error rate is computed. In a last step, we pick the complexity parameter cp for which the cross-validation error rate is minimised.